# log4net won't work based on the assembly attribute

Tags: c#, log4net

I have log4net working with an external config file, by telling my app config where to find the config file and then calling `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`  when the app starts.

```
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  ...
  <log4net configSource="Log4Net.config" />
```

This works, but I now want to watch for changes,According to the documentation I should be able to use the assembly attribute to achieve this, which also means I don't need to call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` any more. So, I add this to the AssemblyInfo.cs for the main app (and also for the project it references):

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Trouble is, this does nothing at all. If I remove the call to `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`, then the logging doesn't work - no logging is initiated. Those attributes don't seem to make a difference. So, I can't get watching the file working at all.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Does your project span multiple assemblies? Also, try enabling debug in the config file so you'll be able to see the `log4net` debug output

Comment: It's a winforms app that references a number of other library assemblies that are part of the solution. Should these all have the attribute?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't harm if you try adding the attribute to one or two assemblies that perform logging and see if it helps. Can't say for sure, but I've used just the same attribute (I mean *literally* the same, even the log file name :)), but the logging was encapsulated in a single assembly that had that attribute.

Comment: Ah - got it - your debug suggestion helped me find the answer - I'll post it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it.

It was because the first logging message came from another assembly. As the [log4net docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) say:

> it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.